# Running command line on MACS for python code

Tags: python, command-line

How do you run the command line in order to read and write a csv file in python on a MacBook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')
df.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how to download the panda library in Brackets (IDE)? I have searched and was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can find everything about reading and writing with csv files in Python here: [CSV File Reading and Writing - Python 3 Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

First, we need to import CSV:

```
import csv
```

Basically, if you want to read a CSV file, first open one up. In the Python Shell (the command line for Python), opening a file in order to read it and storing it in the variable `file` would look like this:

```
with open("filename.csv", newline = '') as file:
     #actions with the file
```

After that, we need to treat the file. Reading the rows from a csv file works as follows:

```
with open("filename.csv", "r") as file:
     csv_content = csv.reader(file)
```

now we want to print the every row of the csv file. We just add the following code:

```
     for row in csv_content:
          print(', '.join(row))
```

If you want to write to a file, it is a bit different:

```
with open('filename.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:                     #1
      writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',                       #2
                             quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL) 
      writer.writerow(["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"])                      #3
```

First, we open the file (1) and specify that we want it to write to it (by adding the parameter `'w'`). Then, we define a writer (2) that we will use to write to the CSV file. At last, we use the writer (3) and add a row to our file with the `writerow` method. Notice that we used a list (`["Row 1", "Row 2", "Row 3"]`). Each element of that list will be converted to a row into the CSV file. Knowing that the list hast 3 elements, we will add 3 rows into the CSV file with the contents `"Row 1"`, `"Row 2"` and `"Row 3"`.

I hope this answers you question as fully as possible. The code I suggested is writeable into the Python Shell, without executing a separate file.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am more concerned with passing arguments into my function that my .py file has created based off of reading a csv file. Specifically, after I drag my directory into the terminal how do I test to see if certain arguments passed into the function?

Comment: My apologies, but I don't completely understand your question. Could you describe to me the action of dragging your directory into the terminal? What do you mean by "certain arguments passing into a function"?

Comment: Sure thing! You take a folder in finder and drag it and paste it into the terminal. It turns into a file path. Then you click enter. Now you’re in the directory where your .py file is and your csv files are. I am having trouble with next step which is testing my .py file to see if it locates any rows or columns with the word neighborhood in them. I need to know what should I put in the terminal in order to see if the test succeeded. I was able to test my code successfully on windows. Just having trouble with mac.

Comment: So you want to execute your .py file via the terminal? In this case simpy use the `python` command followed by the name of the file (extension **included**) and it should execute your python file on the terminal. You may need to specify the python version, if for example you want to use python 3 and it is not the default version. In this case, just type in `python3` or, if you want to be more specific, for example `python3.6` instead of `python`. If your file is called "myfile.py", you would type in `python myfile.py` or `python3 myfile.py` or perhaps `python3.6 myfile.py`.